# Rails: Multiple many-to-many relationships (more than two)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many

Rails newbie here.

While porting models from Django's to Rails I'v got confused with finding best relationships...

Models i want to implement:

- Role (has many Users and Teams)
- User (has many Roles and Software)
- Software (has many Users and one Team)
- Team (has many Software and Documents)
- Patch (has many Teams and Software)
- Document (has many Teams and Software)

Is it possible to build associations with has_many: through or better use has_and_belongs_to ?

I think :through associations will be complicated, 'cause there is more than two cross-relations with given models.

I can see two ways of doing relationships: one big join model or small join models for all current many-to-many relations between models.

```
class Role
  has_many :relations
  has_many :users, through: :relations
  has_many :teams, through: :relations
end

class User
  has_many :relations
  has_many :roles, through: :relations
  has_many :software, through: :relations
end

class Team
  has_many :relations
  has_many :software, through: :relations
end

class Software
  has_many :relations
  has_many :users, through: :relations
  has_one :team
end

class Relation
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :teams
  belongs_to :software
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`has_many :through` gives you the extra flexibility of having a fully functional join model class.  This is required in cases where you want to model some aspects of a relationship beyond the simple fact that the two things are associated with one another.

There's no downside to `has_many :through` as far as i know, other than your codebase might be a line or two bigger, and plenty of advantages.  I would always use `has_many: through`

re the associations being complicated:  draw them all out with a paper and pencil (or a UML-drawing app if you prefer), before doing any coding.  If you previously had a working django app it should be simple enough to map the schema across:  they are both object-relational systems.

Comment: I have a diagram :) but just can't figure how to implement it without flaws... I don't think that join model class is good for storing multiple (more than two) relations. Or am i wrong?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "multiple relations".  A join table is used to model a many-to-many relationship, eg between users and groups, where a user can be in many groups and a group has many users.  The join table/model would be called "group_users" or "group_memberships" or something and each join table record would have a group_id and a user_id.

Comment: Oh wait, i see what you mean with having a single class Relation to do all of the relationships between all the different classes.  To keep things simple i would recommend NOT doing this and instead have a join for each many-many relationship.  You could do it (look up polymorphism) but it will make things more complicated for you and there's not much benefit.